How to find a $7 \times 7$ binary matrix with determinant 32?
This OEIS sequence lists the maximum possible determinant of a square matrix whose all entries are 0 or 1, as a function of the matrix order. For example, the sequence value for $n=6$ is $9$, and there is an example of a 6-by-6 binary matrix with determinant 9:
  1 0 0 1 1 0
  0 0 1 1 1 1
  1 1 1 0 0 1
  0 1 0 1 0 1
  0 1 0 0 1 1
  0 1 1 1 1 0

The sequence value for $n=7$ is $32$, so I would like to see a 7-by-7 binary matrix with determinant 32. How can I find such a matrix?

"For $=7$, the maximum of $32$ is achieved (uniquely) by the incidence matrix of the $2−(7,4,2)$ design (complement of the Fano)." See MO.

You have also asked here, and Will Orrick had a webpage with all such matrices. But they are no longer available. I suppose one can still find them, or write to Will.

After some search here I found binary $n\times n$ matrices having maximal positive determinant. It seems that Will Orrick had a webpage with such matrices. Here are some examples (note that these are band matrices):
$n=6$:
$\quad\det\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\bf{1} & 0 & \bf{1} & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\bf{1} & \bf{1} & 0 & \bf{1} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \bf{1} & \bf{1} & 0 &\bf{1} & 0\\
0 & 0 & \bf{1} & \bf{1} & 0 & \bf{1}\\
\bf{1} & 0 & 0 & \bf{1} & \bf{1} & 0\\
\bf{1} & \bf{1} & 0 & 0 & \bf{1} & \bf{1} \\
\end{array}
\right)
=9;$
$n=7$:
$\quad\det\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
\bf1 &    0 & \bf1 &    0 &    0 & \bf1 & \bf1 \\
\bf1 & \bf1 &    0 & \bf1 &    0 &    0 & \bf1 \\
\bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 &    0 & \bf1 &    0 &    0 \\
   0 & \bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 &    0 & \bf1 &    0 \\
   0 &    0 & \bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 &    0 & \bf1 \\
\bf1 &    0 &    0 & \bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 &    0 \\   
   0 & \bf1 &    0 &    0 & \bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
=32;$
$n=8$:
$\quad\det\left(
\begin{array}
\bf1 &    0 & \bf1 &    0 &    0 & \bf1 & \bf1 &    0 \\
\bf1 & \bf1 &    0 & \bf1 &    0 &    0 & \bf1 & \bf1 \\
\bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 &    0 & \bf1 &    0 &    0 & \bf1 \\
   0 & \bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 &    0 & \bf1 &    0 &    0 \\
   0 &    0 & \bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 &    0 & \bf1 &    0 \\
\bf1 &    0 &    0 & \bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 &    0 & \bf1 \\
   0 & \bf1 &    0 &    0 & \bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 &    0 \\
   0 &    0 & \bf1 &    0 &    0 & \bf1 & \bf1 & \bf1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
=56;$
Also, the matrix for $n=7$ has exactly four nonzero entries in each row and each column.

Unless I've made an error, that matrix for $n=7$ has determinant equal to $31$, not $32$. (?) For cut & paste, the matrix is [[1,0,1,0,0,1,1], [1,1,0,1,0,0,1], [1,1,1,0,1,0,0], [0,1,1,1,0,1,0], [0,0,1,1,1,0,1], [1,0,0,1,1,1,0], [0,1,0,0,1,1,1]] in Python.

@r.e.s. I just computed the determinant, and it is $32$. I wonder how it is possible to obtain $31$?

Okay, sorry for the trouble. (I haven't found my mistake yet, though.)

Right ... I get $32a^7-1$ (obviously incorrect) ... and I've located my programming error -- thanks.

Thanks! How did you find them?

I searched! However, for $n=7$ you can find them yourself by trying band matrices, satisfying some invariants, which are known from the incidence matrix (like exactly four $1$'s in each column and row).

@DietrichBurde Why are band matrices more likely to have a large determinant? And why four 1's in each column and row?

It is not about being more likely. It is about finding just one such matrix. There are $75600$ matrices for $n=7$ with determinant $32$, see OEIS. Taking special matrices is a good strategy. And four $1$'s each row and each column, because it is an incidence matrix of the $2−(7,4,2)$ design (complement of the Fano), see above.
